# How does the javascript at YouTube's login page work to send form data?

Tags: javascript, python, youtube, python-requests

I have been trying for sometime figure out how the js at yt login page works to send the appropriate form data with requests python to log in a youtube account but I still could not after multiple tries to read the code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Modern web site logins are increasingly dependent on Javascript, cookies, and multiple page requests.  They're rarely a matter of simply sending form data, and the methods change with time.  Without running the Javascript code, it can be tricky to make this work and keep it working.

For scripting Youtube access with Python, I recommend using Chrome in the headless mode (`--headless` option).  If you start it with the [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), it's easy to send commands to the browser from Python.